# What is the opposite of must-have?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

I am looking to write a sentence trying to describe the opposite of must-have. The sentence is to be used in a professional setting.

For example, my sentence should look like:

**My must-have for work is a laptop with a long battery life and my [opposite of must-have] is a loud environment.**

So I am to describe what I really need (the must-have) and what I really do not need to be there (opposite of must-have).

Comment: If you embrace the vulgar “must have”, I would have thought the opposite would be obvious.

Comment: They aren't exactly opposites, and "must-have" isn't used in that context. The laptop is an essential tool, but a [must-have](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/must-have) is a not-strictly-necessary but desirable fashion item.

Comment: @WeatherVane — [must-have](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/must-have) : “something that is essential to have or obtain”

Comment: Clearly the opposite of a _must-have_ is a _must-haven't_.

Comment: _bete noire_, _anathema_, etc.

Comment: *My must-have for work is a laptop with a long battery life and my [opposite of must-have] is a loud environment.* => *I need a laptop with a long battery life and a quiet place to work*.  I think OP is looking for a negation for the wrong part of their demands, and has been led into that *cul-de-sac* by the horrid *must-have*.

Comment: A clarification for potential further answerers: the OP mentions 'must-have' which is a newish slangy noun for 'a thing which one must have'. And they seek a counterpart noun for this if it exists as used by people.

Answer (score 4):

How about the noun *deal-breaker*?

> *My must-have for work is a laptop with a long battery life and my deal-breaker is a loud environment.*

> **deal-breaker** *noun*
> **2** something that would cause a person to abandon a plan, mutual arrangement, agreement, or relationship
>  <sub>Source:
> [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/deal-breaker)</sub>

> **must-have** *noun*
> **:** something that is essential to have or obtain
> <sub>Source: [Merriam-Webster
> Online](https://www.merriam-webster.com/)</sub>

(For doubters, both of these nouns are also in the *Oxford English Dictionary*.)

Comment: This is the best fit in conjunction with must-have, and matches the general tone, context, and register, which is fairly casual but business/recruitment-related and office-appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

> My must-have for work is a laptop with a long battery life and my **must-not-have** is a loud environment.

In other words, the author is saying their workplace that *must not have* any loud noises.

Comment: I'm thinking that in Scotland the opposite of a *musta* has to be a [*musnae*](https://findwords.info/term/couldnae). :)

Comment: @tchrist that sounds awfully plausible. I wouldnae put it past them!

Comment: 'Don't-needs' can also be found on the internet ('opposite' being nebulous here) but I can't find dictionary support for either as yet.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I could have written *mustn't've* that's in some dictionary somewhere but I opted for the hyphenated version which mirrored the author's  expression and intention more clearly.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I came here to say this (or "mustn't-have") and it seems to me the most natural construction, but I don't think it has any currency yet (ie this is still in the neologism stage). Any evidence that people use this on the web?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a less strong word, you could call it a **pet peeve.**

[Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/pet_peeve) defines it as follows

> Something that is personally annoying; a personal dislike.